# RN Firebase - FCM : No Vibration

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I know there is many post related about no vibration, but none of it help, so I decide to ask again.

I using latest react-native and latest version of react-native-firebase, by using POSTMAN to test the FCM Send API, follow exactly the document for receiving message.

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.1.4",
"react-native": "0.62.2"

{
    "to":"/topics/feelgood",
    "priority":"high",
    "notification":{
        "sound":"default",
        "title":"Hi, there",
        "body":"Im Programmer and No life"
    }
}
```

Well, everything work fine, when app is in background / quit state are also able to received notification. **The only problem is there is no vibration during receiving.**

What I know, it should work when below have done:

1. I followed the doc to set `sound` param
2. I also insert user permission inside /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`